# graphics.DrawIcon() does not draw on form

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple form on which I want to draw an Icon file from disk.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    'Dim theIcon As Icon = LoadIconFromFile("c:\Users\blabla\pmt.ico")
    Dim theIcon As Icon = New Icon("c:\Users\blabla\pmt.ico",New Size(64, 64))
    g.DrawIcon(theIcon, 20, 20)
    g.Dispose()
    theIcon.Dispose()
End Sub
```

But the Form is loaded empty of any image on it. 
Do you know what am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You have to draw in the `Paint` event of the form. Otherwise, subsequent repaints will erase the icon.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I'll try right now, thanks! It works! If you make the comment an answer I will accept it!

Comment: I'm not sure why you have had a couple of downvotes. It is a perfectly good question - Downvoting should only be on the basis of the quality of your question and not used as a comment on the programming knowledge of the OP.

Comment: @DavidWilson Thanks for caring!